# Lightning cancel button in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, commandbutton

When cancel button is clicked in visualforce page, it has to redirect to home page.Instead I'm getting the same visualforce page.Kindly help.

```
public PageReference cancel()
  {
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Method -

Using **html-5** in doctype in visualforce page means you should use **html-formnovalidate** and immediate in cancel button. For example

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" 
                    html-formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see you have returned "**null**" from "**page reference method**" used for cancel. When you return **null** salesforce keeps redirects to same page. That is the reason when you are using this method, salesforce is keeping you at same page.